# Apple developer Enroll with Two-Factor Authentication

Tags: two-factor-authentication, apple-developer

This week I tried to enroll to the Apple developer program.
Without that I can't publish an App to the store.

When entered in the Enroll program
https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll

It ask me to turn on the two-factor authentication. I did that, inserted my phone number and now every time that I do the login I have to insert my password and my 4-digit sent to the phone.

After I enter again in the Enroll program, it appear a disclaimer again to set the two-factor authentication.

Anyone with the same problem?

Comment: Any solution till now please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a customer support question

Answer (score 11):

Your account is associated with Two Step Verification instead of Two Factor Authentication. You've to switch the account from Two Step Verification to Two Factor Authentication as they're not same thing.Following way, you can switch it-

https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht207198

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same problem, i am developing a multi platform app and dont have an apple device.
Just Contact the Developer support, they will unlock your account so you dont need two-facort authentication:
https://developer.apple.com/contact/#!/topic/SC1101/subtopic/30006/solution/CALL/details

Comment: Yup, I just did this, took me 3 minutes with Apple's developer support

Comment: At least they have quick phone support, though probably should be able to opt out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 2-step authentication is different of 2-factor authentication.

Now to create an apple account and use it to the enroll process, we must login in a iphone, activate the 2-step authentications (settings - turn on 2-step authentication) and receive the digit code in the phone to process to the enroll process...

Comment: That’s true! You have to login into an iPhone to get this working.

Comment: This was a change the apple added not a long time ago? This really sucks

Comment: Yap. It's recent. Even when I called Apple support they didn't know how that worked!